# I would like to create data with python faker with columns that are dependant on each other

Tags: python, dataframe, faker

I have to create a synthetic dataset using faker, in which we have columns that have values that are dependant on each other.

I tried to use standard faker providers, but it seems there is no way to use this to generate dependant data.

For example, I have a column **A** and a column **B**. Whenever the column **A** contains a value **X** the column **B** can only contain certain strings **[ABC, DCB, VBA]**. But if column **A** would contain a value **Y**, then column **B** can only contain values from the list **[QWE, ERY, DSA]**.

Above is an example, but I basically need sort of custom logic and I would like to integrate this using the faker providers. I tried to extend the base provider, but I couldn't find a smart way to do it. Is there an easier, built-in way to do this using faker or some other library?